# csv import to msql only half records imported

Tags: mysql, linux, csv

When I import csv file with 119397 records (4.37 MB) from this command line

```
load data local infile '/var/www/email2.csv' into table email fields terminated by ','  enclosed by '"'  lines terminated by '\n';
```

But only 50199 records imported. Like this 
( Records: 51087 Deleted: 0 Skipped: 0 Warnings 19 )

I want to import all records at once.
Which way should I use?

## Update

[image: warning are here]

Here are table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adv_email` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=22462 ;
```

Here are some of warning records
[image]

Comment: First thing to do `SHOW WARNINGS`. Second thing to do, update question with anything relevent that shows up there. and also show the table structure

Comment: @e4c5 Please look my question again. I edited it .

Comment: Can you add one or two of those offending lines from the CSV into the question as well

Comment: @e4c5 I uploaded some records of offending .Please take a look

Comment: Thank you very much @e4c5 for your SHOW "WARNINGS" mysql command it's help me a lot and now found wrong format data in my csv.
Now I fix and it work!

Comment: Glad to have helped, please feel free to upvote one of my recent answers :)